# SQL query to retrieve all matching columns, many to many relations

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, many-to-many

I have three database tables and I am wondering how I can retrieve all persons who have specific interests, by their interest_id. For example I want to find all persons who have both interest_id 1 and 5. so in this case thats john and scott. How can I achieve this using a SQL query?

person

| person_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | peter |
| 3 | scott |

interests

| interest_id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | skating |
| 2 | climbing |
| 3 | movies |
| 4 | cars |
| 5 | music |

person_interest_relation

| person_id | interest_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |

I have tried to filter with SELECT * FROM person p JOIN person_interest_relation pir ON p.person_id = pir.person_id WHERE pir.interest_id IN (1, 5)

However, this returns all rows where interest_id is either 1 or 5, so in this case it will also return peter since he also has interest with id 5. I only want the rows where both is matching, so 1 AND 5.

PS. The actual database is much larger and this is just a small piece of it. So preferably I need something that can search through it and only return every person with BOTH interests.

Comment: what have you tried? Try it then if you get an error, post your query, the error and expected result. thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question, I apologize for the lacking explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT p.person_id, p.name
FROM person p
INNER JOIN person_interest_relation pir
    ON pir.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE pir.interest_id IN (1, 5)
GROUP BY p.person_id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pid.interest_id) = 2;
```